# How to get the histogram orientation of a 'one' cell according to Dalal and Triggs?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to implement the method of Dalal and Triggs. I could implement the first stage *compute gradients on an image*, and I could create the code who walk across the image in cells, but I don't understand the *logic behind* this stage.

I know is necessary identify first between a `signed` (0-360 degrees) or `unsigned` (0-180 degrees) gradients.

I know I must create a data structure to store each cell histogram, whit n bins. I know what is a histogram, hence I understand I must visit each pixel, but I I don't fully understand about the method for classify each pixel, get the gradient orientation of this pixel and build the histogram with this data.

Answer (score 0):

In short HOG is nothing but a dense representation of gradient orientations weighted by their strengths over a overlapped local neighbourhoods.

You asked what is the significance of finding each pixel gradient orientation. In an image the gradient orientation at each pixel indicates the direction of the boundary(edge between two textures) of the object at that location with respect to X and Y axis. So if you group the orientations of a patch or block or part of an object it represents the distribution of edge directions of object at that region in a very strong way or unique way... Now let us take a simple example, a circle if you plot the gradient orientations of a circle as a histogram you will get a straight line (Don't imagine HOG just a simple plot of gradient orientations) because the orientations of edges of circle ranges from 0 degrees to 360 degrees if u sampled at 360 consecutive locations, For a different object it is different, HOG also do the same thing but in a more sophisticated manner by dividing image into overlapping blocks and dividing each block into cells and making the histogram weighted by the strengths of the local gradients...

Hope it is useful ...

Comment: I guess my question it was not well prepared, I'd like to know the algorithm to get the gradient histogram binning.